# Finding if a plist contains a key with a specific string

Tags: python, plist

Below I have a xml/plist file (you may recognize it as a .tmTheme):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>settings</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Comment</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>comment</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#75715E</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>String</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>string</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#E6DB74</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I'm trying to find if each dictionary contains a string `scope` and if the `scope` has a specific string, say `comment`. Then I need to go to the inner dictionary and retrieve the key `foreground`. In this case, I would need to retrieve `#75715E`.

I've started by using `a = plistlib.readPlist()` then `b = a["settings"]`. Then I'm not sure how I should approach it, keeping in mind I need to find the root dictionary later on so I can get the *other* dictionary in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_plist = plistlib.readPlist()
settings = my_plist["settings"]
for d in settings:
    if "scope" in d:
        if "comment" not in d["scope"]:
            print "A scope with no comment!"
    else:
        print "A dict with no scope!"
```

Comment: Thanks! For the other part (ie. retrieving the other key from the dictionary within), I added after the `if "comment"...` `j["settings"]["foreground"]` (add your own safety checks).